# Page <style> in Header for 11ty

Tags: nunjucks, jamstack, eleventy

I am new to 11ty and Nunjucks, but I cannot find this answer anywhere. I would like to add a page-specific style block in the template head tag from a page. I come from a Vue/Nuxt background, and I really like how you can scope a CSS block to the component/page, and they automatically put it in the head tag for you.

Here is my overall layout:

index.njk

```
---
layout: default.njk
title: Home
---

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/300/sports/5" style="width: 100%;" />
<div class="container">
  <h1>11ty Test</h1>
</div>

{% block customstyles %}
  <style>
    .container{
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

_includes/default.njk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}
      | 11ty Sandbox</title>
    {% block customstyles %}
      This is the default content
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content | safe }}
  </body>
</html>
```

It works to a point, but the style tag is in the body, not the head, and the block doesn't work as I understand it. What am I missing?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: For anyone interested, there is a cool plugin that will do exactly this plus more called Eleventy Plugin Helmet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eleventy-plugin-helmet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use `{% block %}` in a content file ... they can only be used in a file located in `_includes`.  Here is a version of your exmaple that does work ...

#### _includes/default.njk

This is your base layout from which all other layouts "extend"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}
      | 11ty Sandbox</title>
    {% block customstyles %}
      This is the default content
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}
    {{ content | safe }}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

#### _includes/simple.njk

This is the layout just for "simple" pages.  Notice that it uses `{% extends "default.njk" %}` and it uses the `{% block customstyles %}` to provide a custom style.

```html
{% extends "default.njk" %}
{% block customstyles %}
  <style>
    .container{
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<img src="{{ image }}" style="width: 100%;" />
<div class="container">
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  {{ content | safe }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

#### index.njk

This page is just the content, image and title and it is rendered using the "simple" layout.

```html
---
layout: simple.njk
title: Home
image: http://lorempixel.com/1200/300/sports/5
---
 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Sed finibus, velit a tristique hendrerit, nisl nisi aliquet diam, a vulputate tortor quam et odio. 

Vivamus vitae magna a eros suscipit luctus a quis lorem.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. It ignored the blocks and rendered the content the same way I had it before. I tried a few other things and it didn't help.

Comment: @NathanBlaylock ok I see now what I did wrong.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That worked how I wanted it to. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @NathanBlaylock I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your specific styles into front matter data and then show it on the main template.

```
layout: default.njk
title: Home
style: ".container{background: red;}"
```

or if there are long styles then do component and pass the its name in the page header, so your template will include it on the render.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following block to output data in the head of the site

```html
{% block head %}
   {{ yourCode | safe }}
{% endblock %}
```